# Serial monitor in Arduino IDE for RobotDyn ESP8266-Pro via CP2102

Tags: serial, esp8266, arduino-ide

I bought a couple of "ESP8266-Pro" micro-controllers from a Chinese company named RobotDyn.  There's no real documentation with them, but I've bought a lot of other stuff from them in the past that worked out really well, so I took a chance.

After some work, I am [finally able to program the board](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742473/1480995) with the Arduino IDE 1.8.1.

The problem is that I am unable to get the serial monitor working to see what's going on with the code.

What do I need to do to get this to work, or is it simply not possible?  In order to program the board, I need to connect EN to VIN, and both IO0 and IO15 to GND.  I assume I have to disconnect that to actually run the board after programming, but I don't know and haven't gotten anything to work yet.

Here's a photo of the board hooked up for programming.  What do I need to do to restart it with the serial monitor working?

[image: RobotDyn ESP8266-Pro connected for programming with CP2102]

Comment: scroll down https://robotdyn.com/catalog/boards/wifi_module_esp8266_pro_8m_flash/

Comment: I've seen those before. First place I looked. But none of them answer my question in a way I understand, at least. If one of those three docs explain how to connect serially, I'd appreciate it if you explained, more specifically, what I'm not grokking.

Answer (score 1):

You applied connections like it was a plain esp8266. The board has the necessary pull-ups and pull-downs. Connect it at first only to GND, VCC, TX, RX. The button pulls gpio0 LOW to enter flashing mode at power up.

Comment: I'll try just those 4 pins, thanks. But I'm pretty sure I started with that and got nowhere. I'll respond with results later.

Comment: As I thought, I had tried this.  Does not work as you expected.  I consistently get the following errors from the IDE when it attempts uploading: 
`warning: espcomm_sync failed, error: espcomm_open failed, error: espcomm_upload_mem failed, error: espcomm_upload_mem failed`. As I say here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742473/1480995), I am unable to program unless IO15 and IO0 are grounded and EN is run to VIN, regardless of the use of the button.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the trick to being able to monitor serial output on the RobotDyn ESP8266-Pro is to **NOT** have `DTR` and `CTS` from the CP2102 programmer connected to the board's `RST` and `IO12` pins.

With only the four remaining lines connected (`VCC`, `GND`, `TXO`, and `RXI`), you will see normal serial output on the the Arduino IDE's serial monitor **after uploading firmware completes**.

This works for me with the board set as "Generic ESP8266 Module" or as "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)".

This still doesn't get you serial monitoring when you just plug in the device, though.  It only works after firmware has been uploaded.  Still working on that.

Comment: without DTR signal the Serial Monitor doesn't restart the board as you know it from Arduino

Comment: OK, I'll look into that.  I'm not familiar with these serial devices at all - everything I've used had built-in USB except from an Arduino Pro-Min that worked with the programmer cable I got with my CP2102 out of the box.